# Changing labels and breaks with ggplot2 and tsibble

Tags: r, ggplot2, tsibble

Since we can't use `scale_x_date()` with a `{tsibble}` object, what's the approach to change breaks, labels etc?

```
# metapackage
library(fpp3)

# data
melsyd_economy <- ansett %>%
  filter(Airports == "MEL-SYD", Class == "Economy") %>%
  mutate(Passengers = Passengers/1000)

# plot
autoplot(melsyd_economy, Passengers) +
  labs(title = "Ansett airlines economy class",
       subtitle = "Melbourne-Sydney",
       y = "Passengers ('000)") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y", date_breaks = "2 year")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the `tsibble`, the issue is that your `Week` variable isn't of class `Date`. But you could convert it to a `Date` to make `scale_x_date` work:

```r
# metapackage
library(fpp3)

# data
melsyd_economy <- ansett %>%
  filter(Airports == "MEL-SYD", Class == "Economy") %>%
  mutate(Passengers = Passengers/1000) %>% 
  mutate(Week = lubridate::as_date(Week))

# plot
autoplot(melsyd_economy, Passengers) +
  labs(title = "Ansett airlines economy class",
       subtitle = "Melbourne-Sydney",
       y = "Passengers ('000)") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y", date_breaks = "2 year")
```

[image]